# QML window size from child element delegate

Tags: qt, qml

I'm currently trying to create a sort of generic QML component for some tool window I'm planning.

Is there a way to actually set the size of said window according to the size of the `ListView` it contains? The size of the `ListView` would be partly dependent on the model data that its delegate is rendering. Here is a code example, which would be instantiated from somewhere outside:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window{
    id:window
    title: "WindowTitle"
    modality: "ApplicationModal"
    flags: "Dialog"

    ListView {
        id: list
        model: model_inst

        delegate: RowLayout{
            id: list_entry
            Text {
                text: "Model-based variable length text: " + text
            }
            ComboBox {
                model: listrole
            }
            Switch {
               text: qsTr("Switch")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I am trying to access e.g. `list_entry.width` as a source for the window width as `id` does not work since the delegate will probably be used after the initial QML instantiation?
Not sure if there is a way at all or I'm inevitably trying to build some sort of reference loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it will work. The first step I tried in trying to solve your problem was to use `contentWidth`, but http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#flickable-direction says:

> By default, a vertical ListView sets flickableDirection to Flickable.Vertical, and a horizontal ListView sets it to Flickable.Horizontal. Furthermore, a vertical ListView only calculates (estimates) the contentHeight, and a horizontal ListView only calculates the contentWidth. The other dimension is set to -1.

So you have to set `contentWidth` yourself since you're using a vertical `ListView`. If you try to just use the default `contentWidth`:

```
     width: list.contentWidth
```

the window will have no width. So, the best solution is probably to set a width large enough:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: window
    title: "WindowTitle"
    modality: "ApplicationModal"
    flags: "Dialog"
    width: list.contentWidth
    height: list.contentHeight
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: list
        model: 10
        contentWidth: 400
        anchors.fill: parent

        delegate: RowLayout {
            Text {
                text: "Model-based variable length text: " + index
            }
            ComboBox {
                model: 10
            }
            Switch {
               text: qsTr("Switch")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You don't necessarily have to guess it though. You could use e.g. [`TextMetrics`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textmetrics.html) to calculate the maximum text width you're expecting, for example. Though you'd still need to account for the other controls in your `RowLayout`.

If you can use other types besides `ListView`, you could consider e.g. `Repeater` within a `ColumnLayout`, as then you could use its `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight` properties instead:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    id: window
    title: "WindowTitle"
    modality: "ApplicationModal"
    flags: "Dialog"
    width: columnLayout.implicitWidth
    height: columnLayout.implicitHeight
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        id: columnLayout
        anchors.fill: parent

        Repeater {
            id: repeater
            model: 10

            delegate: RowLayout {
                Text {
                    text: "Model-based variable length text: " + index
                }
                ComboBox {
                    model: 10
                }
                Switch {
                   text: qsTr("Switch")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the Repeater and implicitWidth and implicitHeight did the trick for me. Thx Mitch!